# Restore items and scroll position in listview on orientation change

Tags: android, listview, adapter, orientation, restore

I tried, by several means, to restore data of a listview when the user rotate his phone..However, I have some difficulties due to the fact that when I turn the screen once, it works, but when I turn it over another time, it no longer works. In addition, I tried to restore the scroll position but without success.

So I would like to know the best way to do this.

---

My code:

```
private ListView item_container;
private ArrayList<Song.Hits> values;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    item_container = findViewById(R.id.bottom_popup_container);
}
```

And when I finish to retrieve data from an API, I load them into the listview (and I save the data):

```
@Override
public void onRequestFinish(ArrayList<Song.Hits> hits) {
    if (!hits.isEmpty()) {
        CAdapter adapter = new CAdapter(hits);
        item_container.setAdapter(adapter);
        values = adapter.getHits();
    };
}
```

Finally, I overwrite these 2 methods to save the position and the items of the listview.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("list",  values);
        outState.putParcelable("pos", item_container.onSaveInstanceState());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            ArrayList<Song.Hits> values = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");
            if (values != null) {
                CAdapter adapter = new CAdapter(values);
                item_container.setAdapter(adapter);
                item_container.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("pos"));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To an unrelated degree, you should probably be using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`, which nowadays also supports a custom state restoration policy so that the scroll state is automatically preserved until data is set.

Anyways, following current approach, should be as simple as

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
>     ArrayList<Song.Hits> values = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");
> ```

should be

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    values = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also update the OnCreate method or override OnPostCreate method and add the logic you used in onRestoreInstanceState upon checking if savedInstanceState!=null

Comment: it works the first time but when I rotate my phone à second time, the listview disappears

Answer (score 0):

You should do the same checking but on `onCreate` because `onRestoreInstanceState` is not always called, is kind of tricky.

You can check this from the documentation:

> This method is called after `onStart()` when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
>   `savedInstanceState`. Most implementations will simply use
>   `onCreate(Bundle)` to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Move your logic to `onCreate` and you'll be fine

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    item_container = findViewById(R.id.bottom_popup_container);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ArrayList<Song.Hits> values = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");
        if (values != null) {
            CAdapter adapter = new CAdapter(values);
            item_container.setAdapter(adapter);
                item_container.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("pos"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same behavior still remains, it works well the first time but when I rotate my phone another time, the listview disappears..